# Real forms of complex Lie algebras with specified semisimple part

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a complex Lie algebra. If $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple then its real forms are completely understood. In particular there is a compact real form of $\mathfrak g$, which is unique up to inner automorphism.

Suppose $\mathfrak g$ is **not** semisimple and write $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak r \ltimes \mathfrak s$ using the Levi-Malcev theorem, where $\mathfrak r$ is the radical of $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak s$ is a maximal semisimple subalgebra. **Assume that $\mathfrak g$ has a real form**. My question is:

> Can a real form $\mathfrak g_0$ of $\mathfrak g$ be taken so that   $\mathfrak g_0 = \mathfrak r_0 \ltimes \mathfrak s_0$, $\mathfrak r_0$ the radical of $\mathfrak g_0$ and $\mathfrak s_0$ a maximal semisimple subalgebra of $\mathfrak g_0$ which is a compact real form of $\mathfrak s$?

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu Yuan, I have edited the question.

Comment: To be clear, you mean "does there *exist* a real form of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that..."?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Levi Malcev theorem implies that the real form ${\mathfrak g}_0$ has a Levi decomposition whose complexification gives a Levi decomposition of $\mathfrak g$ and by the uniqueness of the Levi decomposition, must be the original Levi decomposition up to automorphism.

Comment: I asked if there exists $\mathfrak g_0$ such that $\mathfrak s_0$ is a compact Lie algebra. But now I think the result is false.

Comment: I think $\mathfrak g= \mathbb C^2 \rtimes \mathfrak{sl}_2\mathbb C$ is a counter example. The only real form is $\mathfrak g_0=\mathbb R^2 \rtimes \mathfrak{sl}_2\mathbb R$.